# Touch events only firing "once" during scroll in Mobile Safari on iPad iOS 11.4

Tags: javascript, ipad, mobile, safari

While scrolling in Mobile Safari, the first `touchstart`, `touchmove`, and `touchend` events are fired, however, if you're still scrolling additional touch events are not fired.

For my application this is problematic because a user can stop the scroll with their finger and I can't tell if there is a finger down. When a finger is down you can't set `scrollTop` of the `window` or rather you can set it, and it changes, but the window doesn't scroll. When the user moves their finger again it starts scrolling not from where I set the `scrollTop` but to whether their finger was put down.

Please no comments on why I want to change the `scrollTop` of the window; let's just accept that as an a priority requirement. Any thoughts for how to detect if there is a finger down?

Comment: Your question is not getting enough coverage because you have not added any source code. Better to add source code snippet and explain problem accordingly.

Comment: @VicJordan correctly said, refer this page -    https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

how about using "detect click on mousedown" like technic? 
something like:

```
var touchStart = false;

function onTouchStart() {
   touchStart = true;
}
function onTouchEnd() {
   touchStart = false;
}
function someFunction() {
   if (touchStart) ...;
   else ...;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot handle touch events when iOs momentum scrolling is active. This also prevents developers from [disabling iOs zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56393464/3089199).