# disable Double tap zoom/resize on safari IOS12***

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mobile, safari

I search 99% website on internet...
nope answer can solve my problem..i am using ios 12...
does any jQuery can totally disable safari double tap now???

or can I have some code detect function when(if user is double tapped?

I spend 2weeks for that i still not find the solution..
This is what i tried...
CSS:

```
* {
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;
  zoom: 1;
  touch-action: manipulation;
}
* {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

and
[disable viewport zooming iOS 10+ safari?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37808180/disable-viewport-zooming-ios-10-safari/50823326)

I hate safari..

Comment: Maybe this works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46167604/ios-html-disable-double-tap-to-zoom

Comment: It seems that this isnt working in iOS 12 anymore. Any idea how to make this work for iOS 12?

Answer (score 17):

Adding an empty click listener on HTML elements will prevent double tap zoom.

It's ugly but does the job.

```
myElement.addEventListener("click", event => {});
```

Next thing i'm trying to figure out to disable all zooming is preventing pinch.

Unfortunately, touch events are not dispatched during iOs momentum scrolling.
The following code works as long as the page is not scrolling (tested only on 12.2) :

```
document.addEventListener("touchstart", event => {
    if(event.touches.length > 1) {
        console.log("zoom plz stahp");
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation(); // maybe useless
    }
}, {passive: false});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is the only solution that I have seen working

Comment: Excellent! iOS/Safari 13.1.2 confirmed.

Comment: Alex, in ios 13 the double tap zoom is disabled. only pinch to zoom works

Comment: Zara website disabled pinch to zoom even when scrolling, in cart page, take a look at their code.

Comment: just tested Zara cart page on iOs 13.3.1 scroll+pinch is not disabled

Comment: the empty click listener isn't working to prevent double-tap zoom for me on `button` elements, which is where my primary zoom problems seem to always be.. anyone else?

Comment: check out the css solution above. works well for me.

Answer (score 9):

Add CSS style `touch-action: pan-y` to `<body>` tag. That's all.

Comment: this solution is the least complicated to simply remove pinching zoom for most use case.

Comment: This disables the pinch gesture not double-tap gesture (IOS 14).

Answer (score 0):

To disable the *double tap* and *pinch gestures* I chose the following combination:

**Disabling double tap**:

```
document.addEventListener("click", event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  event.stopPropagation()
})
```

**Disabling pinch gesture**:

```
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
</head>
```